Dynamically Click on Project File Names Passed in For Loop
I am trying to create a PAD flow that clicks on a Project File. The flow is in a for loop and it passed different file names (all files are in the same SharePoint page). However, everytime I run it, it says it can not find the file name even though I see it open to the correct browser and can see the file with the correct name.
Is this something PAD is able to do or is it really tied to the UI when you record it and it is not able to iterate dynamically?
I even tried to test it with just a hard coded name and it did not work.

